# To replace a string within a for loop in R

Tags: r, string, for-loop

I have many text files

```
fr.txt
no.txt
sta.txt
sto.txt
```

I create a vector with filename as string

```
string <- c("fr","no","sta","sto")
```

And I would like to use for loop in R to use string as the variable names and to read the corresponding files.

```
for (type in c("fr","no","sta","sto")){type <- read.table(sprintf("%s.txt", type),header=TRUE)}
```

For example

```
fr <- read.table("fr.txt",header=TRUE)
no <- read.table("no.txt",header=TRUE)
sta <- read.table("sta.txt",header=TRUE)
```

How should I start with ? The above for loop failed to do what I want.

Comment: *"The above for loop failed to do what I want."* -- what does this mean *specifically*? Also, you are missing a comma before `header = TRUE` in  `read.table(sprintf("%s.txt", type) header=TRUE)`.

Comment: See gregor's answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for some tips that may help.

Comment: Don’t use different variable names, use a list.

Comment: `L <- lapply(paste0(type,".txt"), read.table, header=TRUE)` gives a list of dataframes. `names(L) <- type` sets the names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read all ".txt" files in a directory just use:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.table)
```

**Explained** 
list.files() - grabs your files in your working directory. Suppose you saved your files ("one.txt", "two.txt" etc.) in "C://example" then you have to set your working directory first like

```
setwd("C://example")
```

so that list.files() would know where to search your files. You could also list .csv files if needed by using:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
```

Following that now you can apply read.table function for each ".txt" file in your working directory by using:

```
lapply(temp, read.table)
```

Comment: It will read all of the *.txt file which is not I expected. I only want to read the file I specify.

Comment: So you may use temp = c("one.txt","two.txt"); myfiles = lapply(temp, read.table)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (type in c("fr","no","sta","sto")){
      as.name(type) <- read.table(paste0(type,".txt"), header=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got an error "   Error in as.name(type) <- read.table(paste0(type, ".txt"), header = TRUE) : 
  could not find function "as.name<-"   "

Comment: I'm sorry for that and try this  `for (type in c("fr","no","sta","sto")){
    eval(parse(text = paste0(type,"<-read.table(\"",type,".txt","\",header=TRUE)")))
}`

Comment: another solution like this  `for (type in c("fr","no","sta","sto")){
    assign(type,read.table(paste0(type,".txt")))
}`